# Unity - Point Light not appearing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a `PointLight` to an explosion effect.

However no matter what I try I can't get it to render (the nearby cubes are  unaffected).

**I tried:**

Modifying:

- Position
- Intensity
- Scale
- Range
- Radius

The only way I can get it to work is if I change the type to `Directional`.

**I'm using:**

Unity 2018.3.0f2
High Definition Render Pipeline

//////////

** THE FIX: **

Looks like the Autodesk Interactive material did not reflect light.  After changing the material of the surrounding objects, it works.

Comment: Have you checked the material of the cubes? Some material settings ignore light

Comment: Yeah changed it to the other HDRP materials, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I tried some other materials and got it to work.   Thanks!